# WebDriver FireFoxProfile UserAgent switching with FireFoxDriver

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, user-agent

I'm wondering if I can change the user agent profile on the fly, without creating a new
instance of the ForeFoxDriver? I have the following code, which I can pass in the user agent for iphone or ipad, etc.. it works fine, but i'm having to create a new instance for each test which is slow as it opens/closes the browser. E.g. After doing my tests with iPhone user agent, I'd like to switch the profile to Android user agent or iPad user agent, does the driver get the option to change this without needing to create a new instance?

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override","some user agent, like iphone or iPad");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

// do some tests
// set profile to new user agent
// profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override","some android user agent");

// can i now set the driver to the new profile here and perform more tests on this same instance of the driver?
```

Comment: So far now you can't do this.

Comment: Is there any solution now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RemoteWebdriver (parent class of FirefoxDriver) updates the capabilities map only when the session is starting (in the constructor). Unfortunately we can't modify it elsewhere. I think it is a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably only one way - through extensions. However, I never tried this...

```
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffProfile.addExtension(new File("path/to/extension") );
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);
```

The extension it might work with is User Agent Switcher:
https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/?src=ss

But as stated before, I never did that and have no clue how to control the addon through Selenium

Answer (score 0):

In our company we use Browsermob proxy, an open source proxy written in java. It integrates perfectly with Selenium, and you can control it from your code. It serves us for many purposes, one of them is header manipulation.

The way of doing it is described here: https://github.com/webmetrics/browsermob-proxy (HTTP Request Manipulation section)

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
server.addHeader("User-Agent", uaString)
```